# How to use room and databases without LiveData in android?

Tags: java, android, database

I am new to room and I wanna set up a database for my app. I walked through the documentary for room on developer.android.com. I wrote a little app which uses LiveData and it works fine. Everytime the database changes the underlying data model changes as well.

But for a new app I don't need the LiveData feature. I have a set of data stored in the database which cannot be altered by the app. So it's more or less static. How can I retrieve data from my database without using the LiveData concept?

This would be a first guess:

```
dao.getAllItems();
```

As far as I know queries shouldn't be on the main-thread. 
So I would have to put it in an asyncTask:

```
public class Repository {

private dbDao mDao;
private List<Items> mAllItems;

public Repository(Application application) {
        DB db = DB.getDatabase(application);
        mDao = db.dao();
        new queryAsyncTask(mDao).execute(mAllItems);
    }

private static class queryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Items>, Void, Void> {

        private dbDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        queryAsyncTask(dbDao dao) {
            mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Items>... params) {
            params[0] = mAsyncTaskDao.getAllItems();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

That brings me to the next question. If I fire two or more queries at the same time I need a mechanism to ensure that all asyncTasks have finished like a onFinishedAllLoadingListener. What is the best way to do this? Or is there any easier method to solve my Problem without wrapping each query in a separate asyncTask?

Comment: It's definitely easier on you if when you need multiple queries to be executed at once, you just run them all in `doInBackground`. Beware that the `Void` is supposed to be the value you are returning and receiving in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: RxJava is pretty much industry standard these days. Please consider using http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html for your purpose (and forget AsyncTask for good). There are plenty of examples on SO.

Comment: Room has built in support for [RxJava](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava) and [Coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5)

Comment: @ror I thought he's looking for `Single.zip`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce agree - quite possible, assuming `get` nature of mentioned db requests. I just don't like to write zip functions :)

Comment: @ror I like to zip to tuples. All hail Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I retrieve data from my database without using the LiveData concept?

Don't use `LiveData` as a return type from your DAO methods.

> As far as I know queries shouldn't be on the main-thread. So I would have to put it in an asyncTask

It would be *much* better for you to use `LiveData`, Kotlin coroutines, or RxJava than `AsyncTask`. Even a plain `Thread` or single-thread `Executor` would be better, given that this code seems to be in a repository and not tied to the UI.

In particular, any time you use `AsyncTask` with only `doInBackground()`, there was no need to use `AsyncTask` in the first place, compared to a simple thread. The *only* reason to use `AsyncTask` is because you need `onPostExecute()` to do some work on the main application thread.

And, since `AsyncTask` is considered to be obsolete, I really encourage you to use something else. Room has built-in support for `LiveData`, Kotlin coroutines, and RxJava.

> If I fire two or more queries at the same time I need a mechanism to ensure that all asyncTasks have finished like a onFinishedAllLoadingListener. What is the best way to do this?

In your case, just put them in a single thread. Your code will not have two or more queries at the same time anyway, as `AsyncTask` uses a single background thread by default.

In terms of other likely solutions:

- With Kotlin coroutines, probably `async()` and `await()` are the simplest options
- With RxJava, as EpicPandaForce suggested, use the `zip()` operator
- With `LiveData`, use [a library](https://github.com/adibfara/Lives) that offers a `zip()` operator, or [create your own](https://medium.com/@gauravgyal/combine-results-from-multiple-async-requests-90b6b45978f7)

Comment: I think I need more specific help. Let's assume we are making an app which only displays data from a sql database using room. The data within the database is populated once and never touched again. So the app doesn't change any data within the database. The database consists of one table with two columns "id" and "word". It's basically a list of words. Now we have an activity with one Textview and two buttons ("Next" and "Previous"). The user should be able to toggle through the list of words using the buttons "next" and "previous" while the textview showing the word.

Comment: My idea: Having a LiveData class UiData holding a list of all words and a variable "currentIndex". An Instance of this class is hold by the ViewModel and is observed by the MainActivity. Everytime I change the "currentIndex" the onChange event is triggered in the MainActivity.

But how do I get the words to UiData in the viewModel?

Comment: @Peter: Well, the simplest solution, if you are just going to hold all the words, is to get rid of Room and the database. Just have a `<string-array>` resource of the words, or perhaps use a JSON file in `assets/`. If you are certain that you want to use Room, then have your DAO have a method that returns `LiveData<List<WordEntity>>`, where `WordEntity` is the `@Entity` that represents your table of words. Your viewmodel would either ask the DAO directly or ask the repository, which in turn asks the DAO. Your UI would observe the `LiveData<List<WordEntity>>`.

Comment: To use LiveData<List<WordEntity>> means to implement the onChange in the Activity. But the Data in the sql never changes so this method would never be triggered. Additionally I don't use a RecyclerView to display all words. I just have a TextView for one word. So all the handling would take place in the activity whereas it should actually happen in the ViewModel. So I would rather observe LiveData<List<WordEntity>> from the ViewModel which is not possible (I read about using transformations.switchmap but didn't understand).

Comment: I am probably not the only one who wants to observe LiveData from the ViewModel because that's always the case if the structure of your database doesn't match the structure of your UI. So you have to do something with your data before it can be displayed like in my example extracting an item of a list. Well you could do that in your activity but as I understand the concept that's not the place to do it. How to achieve this in the ViewModel then?

Comment: @Peter: "But the Data in the sql never changes so this method would never be triggered" -- it will when the data is loaded. "So all the handling would take place in the activity whereas it should actually happen in the ViewModel" -- the viewmodel would hold the `LiveData` of the words plus the current word index. The activity would get that data from the viewmodel for rendering. The activity would update the viewmodel when the current word index needs to change.

Comment: @Peter: "that's always the case if the structure of your database doesn't match the structure of your UI" -- the viewmodel transforms the data from the structure from the repository to the structure used by the UI. That does not necessarily mean that the viewmodel is the observer. In a pure `LiveData` scenario (`LiveData` from the repository, `LiveData` from the viewmodel), you would use an existing transformation or write your own. Some prefer to use RxJava/coroutines for the repository stuff, switching to `LiveData` for "the last mile" to the activity, as RxJava/coroutines are more powerful.

Comment: @CommonsWare You say in your answer: Your DAO should not return a LiveData<>. And then, you tell Peter that his DAO should return LiveData<List<WordEntity>> ? I quit don't understand

Comment: @Francky380: The title of the question is "How to use room and databases without LiveData in android?". So, my answer addresses that. Then Peter talked about "Having a LiveData class UiData holding a list of all words and a variable "currentIndex"" in a comment. So, my follow-on comment addresses that.