# Do I have to use LiveData to read Query from Room DataBase in Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-room, android-mvvm

I develop a simple grocery list App using MVVM model.

I have those files:

- `Database` (2 Tables: Shopping Item and Reference Item) + `DAO` (unique)
- `Repository` (Unique)
- `ViewModel` (Unique)
- `Fragment`/`Activity`

In the `DAO`, I define all my queries. Currently, all my `//Custom` queries return a `LiveData<>` type like this:

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingDao {

    // Shopping Items
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertShoppingItem(item: ShoppingItem)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteShoppingItem(item: ShoppingItem)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateShoppingItem(item: ShoppingItem)

    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM shopping_items")
    suspend fun deleteAllShoppingItems()

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM shopping_items")
    fun getAllShoppingItem(): LiveData<List<ShoppingItem>>

    // Custom
    @Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(item_amount),0) FROM shopping_items")
    fun getAllShoppingCount(): LiveData<Int>

    @Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(item_total_price), 0.0) FROM shopping_items")
    fun getAllShoppingTotal(): LiveData<Float>
```

Then in the repository none of them use `suspend fun` to be called. Thus, in the ViewModel they also don't use a `suspend fun` to be called.

I would like to use `getAllShoppingCount()` for example without using a `LiveData` with an `Observer`.

Is it possible ?

Is it a best practice ?

Without the LiveData, I will have to use `suspend fun` to do my `Query`, but when I use:

```
fun updateShoppingItem(item: ShoppingItem) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    repository.updateShoppingItem(item)
}
```

It returns a `Job` not the type the `Query` should return. How can I change that if I can use something else than `LiveData`.

Comment: it should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484682/how-to-use-room-and-databases-without-livedata-in-android

Comment: Thanks but does not rely answer to all the question. I read that before but it just says that Dao should not return LiveData<> an after that ?

Comment: you can't access to database in main thread, so first at all you need to use Dispatcher.IO and then use suspend before dao function and set a return type for it

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts:

1. There is no restriction "you have to use LiveData in Room". There is "you **can** use LiveData" ([link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable)). As well as you can use another techniques implementing pattern Observer - [RxJava](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-rxjava), [Coroutines Flow](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-flow). You **can** use on of these mechanism to achieve reactive flow in your data - something changes in local DB, your Fragment/Activity will observe that change instantly.
2. There is no restriction "you shouldn't use LiveData in Room". In mentioned article it was just an answer - "If you don't want use LiveData - well, then you shouldn't use it". May be, there is some trend to replace LiveData in Kotlin with Coroutines Flow, but it's not demanding now.
3. You can use asynchronous [Coroutines as well](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines). In that case you'll not observe changes in your db. In your viewModel you call your suspend-function easier with the help of [KTX extension](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies)

   `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.updateShoppingItem(item)
   }`
4. But what exactly use, there are too many "you can use this" and "you can use that"? Well, as usual - it depends, and there is no single best-method, and there are lot of "if". If you don't need to observe changes in your data on-line and you use Kotlin and you're familiar with coroutines - you can use them. If you use Java in that case and you're not familiar with RxJava and you don't want to study it (still why?) you have to bother to manually move all your code working with db into another Thread. If you a RxJava fan - you can use it even if you use Kotlin. If you a RxJava fan but you want to be on the edge of trends - you can use Flow.

Hope this will help.